# Integrating PassportJS inside ExpressJS application error

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I've been trying to integrate PassportJS inside my node application running on top of Express for almost a day now, and i've been going back to the same error. It's either i get a bad request, or i receive a `POST /login 404`. I really need your help.

My app is quite simple.

Here is my **app.js** file, where i declared passport :

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
}, 
function(username, password, done) {
        db.User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
            console.dir("Finding");
            console.dir(username);
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
            }
            if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  db.User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

I've already added the following inside **app.js** too :

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

The **routes** file :

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('../models/user');

var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'BizTapp' });
});

router.get('/login', function(req,res){
    res.render('login', { title: 'Login' });
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), 
        function(req,res){
            res.redirect('/');     
});

module.exports = router;
```

And my **html** file :

```
<% include auth-header %>
    <div class="login-panel">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <form method="post" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">User Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                      </div>
                      <input type="submit" id="btn-login" value="Log In" />
                    </form>
                    <h4><a href="/signup">Create a new account?</a></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% include footer %>
```

**models/user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {
    username : { type: String },
    password : { type: String }
});
```

I've already created my **model** for users, yet i am redirected to page that says bad request. Inside **console**, i see a `POST /login 400`.

What else have i missed or what else should i do? Or, what should i keep in mind when i try to integrate PassportJS in my app? I would really appreciate any help.

I have just begun studying node, and i'd really like to start with this basic feature (which is authentication).

Comment: `404 error` is "Page Not Found". Maybe occurred with missing routes or incorrect url.
`400 error` is "Bad Request". Maybe occurred with incorrect input value or body-parser not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the configured passport object in the routes. Not through a new require.

Change the routes file to export a function that takes the passport object as a parameter and use that.

Here is a tutorial: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Comment: Thank you so much for this awesome tutorial. It did solved my problem. :)